# django admin Model edit form - How to filter foreignkeys to only related models

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an account model in django which has a foreignkey to `Payment` and a onetoone to `Address`.

In the Account section in the admin, I can edit a specific model and edit the fields `payment` and `address` via a select widget.  However how can I filter the options so that it only shows related models. (ie not every address or payment from every user, only the ones from that user).

The `RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter` seems to only apply to the model list view. Is there a way to use this in the model edit view?

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is call [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines). It allows you to edit related object directly in the parent model form which in this case would be the `Account` model. Here is an example of implementation:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Payment(models.Model):
    account= models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Adress(models.Model):
    account= models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adress= models.CharField(max_length=100):

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        Paymentinline,
        Adressinline,
    ]
```

Note that this is not a complete implementation (you will need to construct both inlines), follow the documentation on inlines for further information but above are the basics to it.

Comment: Thanks but the relationship is the other way round,  an account can have multiple payment options, and the onetoone relationship is defined on account not on address.  I don't need to fully edit them (though that would be fine too) but just reselect eg which payment to associate with the account (but only that user's payment not a payment method from every user).